# How to force the my url not to change the value of '#'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an URL address that I change dynamically I it goes something like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Method","Controller", new { Id = Model.DId, dbId = Model.DbId, iconId = Model.IconId, edition = Model.Edition })"></a>
```

The dynamic part is the -> **edition = Model.Edition**.Usually it as an integer value and the url ends up something like that: ....**&edition=1232113** . Sometimes I need it to end up like that : **&edition=1232113#10_11** and I managed to pass th right value to the **edition** placeholder but after the reload it doesn't show the same url that I expected it is similar but it substitutes the '#' with '%23'. And it looks something like that: **1232113%2310_11** and the effect is not what I expect.

From the other side, when I type it manually : **1232113#10_11** it works.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

If you problem is concerning that the Url.Action is converting a part of your url, you may want to use the RAW method.

```
@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Method","Controller", new { Id = Model.DId, dbId = Model.DbId, iconId = Model.IconId, edition = Model.Edition })
```